# How to get nested objects with angular

Tags: angularjs, nested

Right now i'm doing a fetch with a very ease service this is the code.

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/Users/:id', { id: '@_id'}, {
        update: { 
            method: 'PUT' 
        }
    }); 
}]);
```

and i do the fetch to all objects like this

```
    var users = User.query();
```

On user schema there's a property with a custom object and when i do the query i just receive an array of ID instead of the whole objects.

How do i do populate on angular JS since i'm doing User.query();

Thank you.

Comment: You would need to post your server-side request handler...

Comment: Either need to do more at the server to look up all the data and combine it with what is already sent or make individual requests from client using those object ID's. We don't know enough about how your back end or data is configured

Comment: how can i do this ? i mean exactly how can i populate the same object i get from the query?

Comment: I use express-testify-mongoose for the routing does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've figure it out! :) it turns out the library i'm using "express-testify-mongoose" have a prebuilt route /api/v1/User/:id?populate=customProperty

when i do User.get() or User.query() with this service , it has customProperty populated.